# How to itearate over grep context groups in bash

Tags: bash, loops, awk, grep

Grep, with the capture context option (-C), produces a text file with the captured groups separated by '--'. How can I loop over the whole groups in bash? Not just the lines, but the whole groups complete with \n characters. I'd like to loop over the groups and process them by another grep command.

Using a test file so.txt:

```
line 1
word
line 3
line 4
line 5
word ...other text
phrase ...yet another text
line 6
line 7
```

the following grep:

```
grep -C 1 "word" so.txt
```

produces:

```
line 1
word
line 3
--
line 5
word ...other text
phrase ...yet another text
```

A sketch of what I'm trying to use it for:

```
function searchGroup {
    grep1=$(grep "word" -A 1 "$1")
    if grep "phrase" "$grep1"; then
        echo "$1"
    fi
}

grep "word" -C 1 so.txt | {
    group=""
    while IFS= read -r line; do
         if [[ "$line" == "--" ]]; then
              searchGroup "$group"
              group=""
          else
              group+="$line"$'\n'
          fi
    done
    if [[ -n "$group" ]]; then
         searchGroup "$group"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `awk` with the record separator `RS` set to `^--$`

Comment: "Capture context option"? It just outputs one line above and below.

Comment: *loop over the groups and process them by another grep command*; what is this other `grep` command? this sounds like one small part of a bigger processing requirement ... what is the overall processing requirement?

Comment: @KamilCuk man page calls it "Context Line Control"

Comment: @markp-fuso edited the question

Answer (score 1):

> How can I loop over the whole groups in bash?

You may read line by line up until the `--` line and then parse....:

```
.... | {
group=""
while IFS= read -r line; do
     if [[ "$line" == "--" ]]; then
          echo "group is $group"
          group=""
      else
          group+="$line"$'\n'
      fi
done 
if [[ -n "$group" ]]; then
    echo "and the last group is $group"  
fi
}
```

But usually it's simpler is to replace the magic `--` sequence by a unique *single* byte, preferably by a zero byte, and then read it up until that byte, with bash extension and GNU sed:

```
... | sed 's/^--$/\x00/' |
while IFS= read -r -d '' group || [[ -n "$group" ]]; do
     echo "group is $group"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. The first one works well, the second one doesn't return the last group.

Answer (score 1):

A single `awk` can handle this easily by grouping before/after lines along with matched line in one single string:

```sh
awk -v C=1 -v w='word' -v kw='phrase' '$0 ~ w {
   s = p ORS $0
   if (getline > 0)
      s = s ORS $0
   if (s ~ kw)
      printf "%s\n", s
}
{
   p = $0
}' so.txt
```

```
line 5
word ...other text
phrase ...yet another text
```

Comment: @OndrejSotolar: Please check my updated answer on getting it done in a single `awk` what you're trying to do with multiple `grep` + shell loop.